# Proof of Ramanujan's identity

Tags: logarithms

I'm having trouble understanding Ramanujan's formula from his proof of Bertrand's postulate, namely:
$$ \ln \lfloor x\rfloor!=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\psi\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) $$ 
where $ \ln x = \log_ex$.
Could someone explain me step by step, how to prove the formula? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: It's the Chebyshev function, psi. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: the definition of the function is $ \psi(x)=\sum_{p\le x} k \log p $.

Comment: What is k in your def'n of Chebyshev function?

Comment: I'm quoting Wikipedia: the second Chebyshev function $ \psi(x) $ is defined similarly, with the sum extending over all prime powers not exceeding x: $ \psi(x) = \sum_{p^k\le x}\log p $. Sorry, I misstated the definition. Thanks for patience ;D

Comment: At the moment this is an interesting yet poorly constructed question.

Answer (score 2):

For this proof we will use the definition

$$\psi(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)$$

and the identity

$$\log n = \sum_{d|n} \Lambda(n)$$

which is proven [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_Over_Divisors_of_von_Mangoldt_is_Logarithm).

Now

$$\log [x]! = \sum_{n \le x} \log n = \sum_{n \le x} \sum_{d|n} \Lambda(d)$$

$$ = \sum_{ed=n} \Lambda(d) = \sum_{e \le x} \sum_{d \le x/e} \Lambda(d)$$

$$ = \sum_{e \le x} \psi(x/e).$$